# How to fix PCL All-In-One installing error, PATH too long installer unable to modify PATH

Tags: visual-studio, kinect, point-cloud-library, openni

I want to install PCL-1.9.1 for visual studio 2017 and OpenNI2 to get point cloud from kinect V2. The problem is I can not install AllinOne PCL because it gives me path too long installer unable to modift PATH.

Even I clear the path and %50 of it is empty, I still keep getting this error. Anybody knows something to fix it?

The error I get:

[image: i]